# Over event of droppable isn't working correctly, after draggable is dropped on greedy droppable and dragged again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The circumstances under which the over event isn't triggered are best explained by the following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wevebasoba/1/edit?js,output).

Do the following:

1. Drag the draggable(yellow) over the droppables(red and blue), on the over event the droppables change their background color to green and on the out event they change their background color back.
2. Drop the draggable on the inner droppable(blue).
3. Drag the draggable over the outer droppable(red), it should change its background color to green, but it doesn't! The over event isn't fired but when you leave the outer droppable again its out event does fire. From there on it works again as expected.

I think this behaviour is a bug. Should I create a bug ticket?

EDIT:

The same behaviour is also achieved if I just set a hoverClass for the droppable options. See following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/movewikoqi/1/edit?js,output). This has to be a bug, because the behaviour is inconsistent. After dropping the draggable in the inner droppable the behaviour is different.

Comment: seems to be a bug. raise it in github. jquery ui team will clarify

Comment: Its a known issue. Take a look at this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053289/jquery-droppable-greedy-not-working-as-expected#answer-17588198)

Comment: @AnkitSaroch I don't think this is related to this answer. The answer and the closed bug ticket state, that if the draggable is released inside of a greedy droppable all parent elements won't receive the drop event. In my jsbin this is working correctly and I desire it work like that. But after dropping it in the inner droppable and dragging a new one, the over event of the outer droppable won't fire.

Comment: Sorry, for getting the question wrong at first, there is already a ticket open for this issue. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10111

Comment: @AnkitSaroch Thank you. That's exactly the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a workaround:

By investigating the behaviour, there had to be some logic in the out event which didn't happen in the drop event. Every time the draggable enters a greedy droppable some logic is applied to prevent ancestor droppables from firing their drop event. In each out event this logic is reset and this reset is missing in the drop event. So I took the needed parts from the out event and implemented them into the drop event.

See the following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/keronolofu/1/edit?js,output)

I can already apologize for not opening a bug ticket. If someone wants to do that please go ahead.

EDIT:

Ankit Saroch pointed out that there is already a bug ticket for this issue and also a simpler workaround exists. Check his comment below the question text.